# Woocommerce checkout fields one under the other

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My question is simple, I have avada theme installed on wordpress and I use woocommerce as my plugin, the question is: how can I have those 3 fields one under the other?

Billing address, Shipping Address and Review & Payment not to be on columns (steps) like is now.

Here is a print screen to see how I see the columns now. Thank you in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step One:  Download Filezilla**

To achieve your goals here, you are going to need to access your web files, on your server.  One of the ways you can achieve this, is by downloading [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php).  Once downloaded, you can enter your login credentials on the opening screen, to access your web files.  Unfortunately, this method is not the most secure.  Follow [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-filezilla-to-transfer-and-manage-files-securely-on-your-vps), which shows you how to access your webfiles, via Filezilla, more securely.  It looks more complicated than it actually is.

**Step Two:  Create a Child Theme**

Once you are all logged in, you are going to need to create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).  What you are doing here, is essentially creating a series of overrides.  When someone heads to your website, the Parent Theme loads in the background and then the Child Theme loads, overriding the desired Parent Theme files, prior to displaying the content in the browser.

You can edit the Parent Theme files directly but this would not be a good idea.  Firstly, it will be more difficult to resolve any errors, should you make a mistake.  Secondly, any edits you create will be removed whenever you upload any Theme updates.  As good practice, you want to leave the Parent Theme files alone and only place your own customisations in your Child Theme.

**Step Three:  Create your overrides**

Your next step, is all about creating your overrides.  To find the location the files you will need to override, head into the following file directory:

> wp-content > themes > theme-name > woocommerce

Drag and drop the 'woocommerce' folder onto your computer.  This will not remove the 'woocommerce' from the Parent Theme, so do not worry about that.

Then head into your Child Theme and drag the 'woocommerce' folder into your Child Theme.

**Step Four:  Alter the information**

Due to every theme being different, it is not possible for me to tell you exactly which WooCommerce file needs to be edited here or where in each file, you need to place your modification(s).  As an educated guess, you may need to edit files such as:

- `form-shipping.php`
- `form-billing.php`
- `review-order.php`
- `payment.php`
- `payment-method.php`
- `form-pay.php`

Focusing on the WooCommerce files you dragged and dropped to your computer, you will need to open each file, using a piece of software, such as [Notepad++].[4](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.3.html)  Simply right click on each file and select 'Open with Notepad++'.  You will then need to spend a little time identifying which file and where in that file, you need to perform your modification(s).  When you do each modification, simply drag the file back over into the 'woocommerce' folder within your **Child Theme** and refresh your browser to see if the changes have occurred.  This will require some trial and error.

**Step Five:  Deleting unmodified files**

Once you have successfully achieved your goal(s), delete all of the 'woocommerce' files, within your **Child Theme**, which you have not modified.  This will ensure that the only WooCommerce files, in your Child Theme, are **only** those which you have modified.

Comment: Hi Craig, Thank you for your anwser. My theme is Avada, I have done all the steps, I have identify few of the words that i wanted to be changed, I also think that i need to modify somewere in these files, but i didnt find out in which and what :(  form-shipping.php
form-billing.php
review-order.php
payment.php
payment-method.php
form-pay.php

Comment: also form-checkout is an option no?

Comment: Hi @SasoriAkatsuki Possibly.  As I am not 100% sure on how your theme developer has modified the WooCommerce template files, I could not give a definite answer.

Comment: OK, thank you anyway Craig. Have a nice day/night :)

Comment: And yourself.  Good luck with your changes.  Don't forget to tick my answer as the correct/accepted one, if it has helped solved your query, as to let others know it works.  If you need further help, let me know and I will see what I can do for you. :-)